# Implicit (inherited objects) in Java, more suited way?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, junit, polymorphism

I have the feeling that using parent's variables is kind of shabby. It has to be a way to enforce the visibility in a subclass to make it more explicit.

```
public abstract class MyClass{

   @Autowired
   Object implicitObject;

   @Test
   public void commonTest(){
        implicitObject.doSomethingBasic();
   } 
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass{

   @Test
   public void testSomethingElse(){
         implicitObject.doSomethingElse(); 
   } 
}
```

Do you think it is a well esteemed pattern? Is there any optimal alternative?

Comment: I don't like to expose parent class variables. It's kind of dangerous as unless you make it final any subclass can destroy/replace it. It's then difficult to protect your API from bad usage. Optimal alternative in your case: why don't you put doSomething() in MyClass ? Or you can implement and use a final getter for implicitObject on the super class.

Comment: That's exactly my fear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Protect the field**

Exposing parent class member is generally not a good idea, unless the field is declared final (which is often impossible) it can be damaged or [hidden](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) by a child class.
It's preferable to protect it by a getter method. While it does make the implicitObject more "visible" it's protected from "malicious" child classes.

```
public class MyClass{
   @Autowired
   private Object implicitObject;

   public final Object implicitObject() {return implicitObject;}
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass{
   public void doSomething(){
         implicitObject().doSomething(); 
   } 
}
```

Is it good practice?

Yes but it depends on what's behind implicitObject, if it's some sort of Context or Resource the API will sound fine to me.

---

**Control access with a visitor interface**

If you want to add more "constraint" there is another solution : expose your implicitObject as a method parameter, this adds more "visibility" to your implicitObject but involve more boilerplate code. (inspired by the visitor pattern)

```
/**
 * Class to implement for custom tests
 * Enable access to low-level implicitObject
 */
public interface CustomTest {
    void test(Object implicitObject);
}
```

```
public class MyClass{

   @Autowired
   private Object implicitObject;

   @Test
   public void commonTest(){
        implicitObject.doSomethingBasic();
   }

   /**
    * method that accept the visitor and give access to implicitObject
    */
   public final void customTest(CustomTest customTest) {
       // You can prepare some stuff before
       customTest.test(implicitObject);
       // You can cleanup after
   }
}
```

CustomTest is the only way to get access to implicitObject :

```
public class MyCustomTest implements CustomTest {
    @Override
    public void test(Object implicitObject) {
        implicitObject.doSpecificThing();
    }
}
```

Then use your visitor implementation.

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass{
   @Test
   public void testSomethingElse(){
       super.customTest(new MyCustomTest()); 
   } 
}
```

It's verbose... Is it worth the effort? Again it depends on what's behind implicitObject.

---

**Use your container**

I don't know if it's possible/practicable with Spring but some container should be able to inject implicitObject as method parameter.

```
public abstract class MyClass{
   @Autowired
   Object implicitObject;

   @Test
   public void commonTest(){
        implicitObject.doSomethingBasic();
   } 
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass{
   @Test
   @Autowired
   public void testSomethingElse(Object injectedImplicitObject) {
         injectedImplicitObject.doSomethingElse(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Well that mechanism would fix the overriding problem but not the visibility one, I feel somehow I force to use an implicit method (instead of an object). That means the class forces you logically but not physically to use a part not defined in the visible API at all. It stills seems to me somehow that can be improved

Comment: Yes because it depends on who is controlling the logic. There is two approches : You have a parent class that offer a bunch of utility method and methods are actually run on child class. But if you want to enforce particular logic then it's up to the parent to do all the logic a call overridable methods. Abstract/Interface are good for that.

Comment: But maybe I totally missed the point, a more concrete example could help. Reading your code I don't get exactly where you want to go. Do you want to force child classes to call a specific parent class method whenever they do something?

Comment: I am just asking if that is a best practice solution and if not, how to model the API in a more polished way

Comment: (may the gods forgive me the downvote but i dont consider this a legit answer to the visibility problematic since now there is just a inherited method rather than a inherited field beeing used). But end this right away, i am with you nomoa and we would need a more complex example to talk about.

Comment: @user1902288 no problem :), I added another solution maybe this one is better?

Comment: @nomoa Yup, i like it way more now! (thus the upvote). If you have any source on how the "protect the field" approach is good practise i would enyoj raeding it.

Comment: @user1902288 protected field is considered bad practice (there's tons of pitfalls related to them)  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/why-is-clean-code-suggesting-avoiding-protected-variables . The solution "Protect the field" limits some problems : unsafe synchronization, variable destruction, API evolution and backward compatibility problems... In other words protecting the field will offer you more possibilities to fix bad design/usage of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make it explict by adding this

```
this.implicitObject.doSomething();
```

It wont get any better than this. The visibility is already "enforced" as much as can be (since the variable obviously is visible in the child).

Any other matters regarding "how the developper sees the visibility" of inherited fields do adress the way a IDE displays such fields (like in Eclipse they are just the same as the childs, Intellij displays them as inherited fields, etc.)